# How to use SOAP web service in User Interface?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jsp, soap

I am doing web service now, and already succeed installing SOAP in my web service..
It is working perfectly when i "run as java application".. (I use eclipse as my environment)

Here is my client method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LogbookSOAPServiceLocator locator = new LogbookSOAPServiceLocator();
    try {
        LogbookSOAP logbookSOAP = locator.getLogbookSOAPPort();
        System.out.println(logbookSOAP.fetchLog("21").getDriverName());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This succesfully work in console, can i use it anywhre in my user interface? like .jsp file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. At first you need to install [web container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) to deploy your application. Then create web project. [Step by step tutorial by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/webapplications/workshopJSP/tutorialJSP/TutorialJSPMakeJSP.html) based on Oracle WebLogic Server but you can use other one.

The simpliest way to using JSP Scriptlets and put all our logic in JSP page.

```
<%@page import="your imports here"%>
........ 
<%
LogbookSOAPServiceLocator locator = new LogbookSOAPServiceLocator();
    try {
        LogbookSOAP logbookSOAP = locator.getLogbookSOAPPort();
        System.out.println(logbookSOAP.fetchLog("21").getDriverName());
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

But it is not really good way because as your know best practice is to avod code logic in JSP pages especially Scriptets [JSP coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html). Better code it in java wrapper class which you can call from JSP and after executing it will return result to the page.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot.. but can you give an example for how to call SOAP in the jsp? Thanks